# Is the use of an article (the) appropriate here?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, definite-article, determiners

In general, a singular common noun is always preceded by an article - a, an, or the.

Applying the same rule in the following sentence, we get

1) He is good at **the** word prediction.

I precede **word** with **the** since **word** is singular common noun. However, I am not referring to a specific **word**, like in sentence

2) He is good at **the hidden word** prediction.

Hence, I feel in sentence 1, preceding **word** with **the** doesn't sound proper, and I expect sentence 1 to be in the following form.

3) He is good at word prediction.

But, with sentence 3, I break the rule by not preceding a singular common noun --word-- with an article.

Please elaborate if 1 or 3 is correct (or both)? Why?

Thanks.

Comment: *word prediction* is an activity, not a thing. So no article is used. BTW 1 is not correct. You can't judge by "word", since it is a modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ear is right.  1 is incorrect.
'The' should not be used in that case.  If you put 'the' in front of 'word' in the first sentence, it is not referring to the singular noun 'word', it is referring to 'word prediction'.  'Word' in this sentence is an adjective modifying 'prediction'.

2 is correct, though it is a less common usage.  It works without 'the' in the same way that 1 does not need 'the'.  With 'the' it distinguishes 'hidden word prediction' from other kinds of 'word prediction' that might be present in this context.

3 is correct.
Here's one way to tell.

> He is good at word prediction.

means the same thing as

> He is good at predicting words.

Update:Modified my answer to reflect points @Flair brought up in comments.

Comment: But this doesn't explain why you couldn't say "He is good at predicting *the* words."

Comment: @Tofystedeth  Thanks, your explanation is good. **word** in sentence 1 and 3 function as **adjective** , hence article **the** is inappropriate.

However, the use of **the** in sentence 2 is not wrong.

**hidden word** contextualizes **prediction** (common noun). Hence, you are taking about a specific type of prediction.

so use of definite article **the** is appropriate in sentence 2.

Comment: @user3169 "He is good at predicting the words." is acceptable.
By **the words** you are referring to specific set of words that the reader is already aware of. (may be spanish words).

Comment: @Flair You're right, it is correct to use, but less common, as it changes the implied meaning to be more specific.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Flair I wasn't saying you couldn't say it, just that this answer implied you shouldn't/couldn't.